# sorting a list per dateTime inside a class

Tags: c#, datetime, queue

I have created a class, which contain a string, byte array and a datetime variables.

also created a queue for for this class,

I want to sort the queue per the datetime which is inside the class

what is the best way to do that to compelte the method sortQueue?

```
 public class DataToPassOn
{
    public DateTime dt;
    public byte [] Data;
    public string  ComName;

    public DataToPassOn(int length)
    {
        dt = new DateTime ();
        Data = new byte[length];
        ComName="";
    }

}
 public class sorting
  {
      private Queue<DataToPassOn> _QdataToPassOn;

       public sorting ()
       {
          _QdataToPassOn = new Queue<DataToPassOn>();
       }

       public void sortQueue ()
       {
       }

   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396657/sort-a-queue-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1448270/2130976

Comment: this examples are not for datetime? do you have a code exmple which sort by the datetime?

Comment: would be happy to get an exmple of datetime

Comment: Agreed with @Irshad, the very definition of a queue would be for a FIFO manner, as linked in the first SO. You are better off using a List and ordering on that collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to sort your queue:

```
_QdataToPassOn = new Queue<DataToPassOn>(_QdataToPassOn.OrderBy(x => x.dt));
```

Comment: but how should I replace x? does I need to replace x with dt?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code with `dt`. You don't need to replace x with dt, this is a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). The x is like a temp variable with an object of type `DataToPassOn`.