# generic class supports duplicated key

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate keys in .NET dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries)

I want to use a kind of dictionary which can support duplicated keys. Is there any builtin support in .Net framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries

Comment: @user , if you want a quick fix , you can multiply the key by number which makes the key unique and add it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

No but you can use List it doesnt have key values instead of you can store like
List.add( key,value)