# Allow duplicate keys with ToDictionary() from LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, duplicates

I need the Key/Value stuff from a Dictionary. What I do not need is that it does not allow duplicate Keys.

```
Regex template = new Regex(@"\{(?<key>.+?)\}(?<value>[^{}]*)");
IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = template.Matches(MyString)
                                             .Cast<Match>()
                                             .ToDictionary(x => x.Groups["key"].Value, x => x.Groups["value"].Value);
```

How can I return the Dictionary allowing duplicate keys?

Comment: Is it possible to use List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries

Comment: Maybe he was testing if the Stackoverflow Dictionary allowed duplicate keys? :-P

Comment: @Alex ToLookup does not help in my case. I need the Key/Value access for later usage...

Comment: how do you expect the key -> value lookup to work with duplicate keys? Either it's not going to work, or you want to group by the key value first.

Comment: @msfanboy: you could access values by key by using an indexer; e.g. `dictionary[key]` this will get you an object of type `IEnumerable<string>` which holds your values.

Comment: Why not just groupBy(key) and store group.ToList() as Value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class:

```
Regex template = new Regex(@"\{(?<key>.+?)\}(?<value>[^{}]*)");
ILookup<string, string> dictionary = template.Matches(MyString)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .ToLookup(x => x.Groups["key"].Value, x => x.Groups["value"].Value);
```

**EDIT:** If you expect to get a "plain" resultset (e.g. `{key1, value1}`, `{key1, value2}`, `{key2, value2}` instead of `{key1, {value1, value2} }, {key2, {value2} }`) you could get the result of type [`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx):

```
Regex template = new Regex(@"\{(?<key>.+?)\}(?<value>[^{}]*)");
ILookup<string, string> dictionary = template.Matches(MyString)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x =>
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
            x.Groups["key"].Value,
            x.Groups["value"].Value
        )
    );
```

Comment: yes of course I can do this, but then I have to use the for-loop AND I can not access the Value. I can only find the Keys property ?

Comment: @msfanboy: the `Dictionary` maps key to value when `Lookup` maps key to one or more values. the `Dictionary` doesn't allow several values to have the same key when `Lookup` does. What kind of structure do you expect to return?

Comment: very good solution Alex! Exactly what I meant. I tried List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> but I missed your Select :)