# Is there an equivalent to SortedList(of string, string) that accepts non-unique keys

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What I need is to be able to put in a SortedList a combination of two fields that are non-unique, but the pair is (like database composite keys).

More precisly, i have my list, and i want to be able to do this with it

```
Dim myList = New Generic.SortedList(Of String, String)
myList.add("aaa","aaa")
myList.add("aaa","bbb")
myList.add("bbb","bbb")
myList.add("bbb","aaa")
```

This would throw an exception as "an entry with the same key already exists"

I know i could make my own object and a list of that object, but is there anything that already exists for what i want to do?

Thanks

Comment: Well, the built-in thing is a `Tuple`, but it doesn't handle comparison for you. You'll have to make your own class.

Comment: From what i see, i could do a `tuple(Of String, String)` but i would still need to do a `list(Of myTuple)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class. Jon Skeet provided a good answer on that subject. [c# duplicate Keys in .NET dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/146227/1028323)

You first have to store them in a enumerable object though `IEnumerable(Of (Tuple(Of String,String))` for example)

```
        Dim compositeKeys = New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String))
        compositeKeys.Add(New Tuple(Of String, String)("aaa", "aaa"))
        compositeKeys.Add(New Tuple(Of String, String)("aaa", "bbb"))
        compositeKeys.Add(New Tuple(Of String, String)("bbb", "aaa"))
        compositeKeys.Add(New Tuple(Of String, String)("bbb", "bbb"))

        Dim lookup = compositeKeys.ToLookup(Function(x) x.Item1)
        Dim aaaKeys = lookup("aaa") // 2 hits
```

For a specific lookup, there is always `LINQ`

```
Dim specificLookup = lookup("aaa").Where(Function(x) x.Item2 = "bbb").FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: Would I be able to look for a specific tuple of data? Let's say i'm looking for the ("aaa","bbb") tuple.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But Tuples are part of the 4.0 framework, and so I won't be able to use them.

Comment: You can just define a class with two generic properties pre 4.0.