# String Indexer for List of Classes

Tags: c#, string, list, indexing

I have a class that I created below

```
 public class Program_TFT
{     
    public string ProgramName;
    public int NumberOfProjects;
    public List<Project> Projects = new List<Project>();        
}
```

and I created a list with this class

```
public static List<Program_TFT> Programs = new List<Program_TFT>();
```

I need to be able to call elements of lists with string indexer instead of integer.
Like this it works

```
 Programs[Programs.FindIndex(x => x.ProgramName == "Prog_1")]
```

But instead of that I want to create a direct string indexer like this

```
 Programs["Prog_1"]
```

What can I do? Thanks

Comment: I'd change your list in the a dictionary with a string key.

Comment: Instead of `Programs[Programs.FindIndex()]]`, you could use `Programs.Single(p => p.Name == "Prog_1")`. But yeah, you might want to consider using a dictionary as Kevin suggested. Alternatively, you could write your own class which [extends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/8967612) `List<Program_TFT>`.

Comment: This seems to be the solution at this moment, will need to change lots of code though, I was wondering if there would be another way to do it. Thank you Kevin Smith

Comment: I will try the solution Kevin has suggested. Thank you 41686d6564

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# collection indexed by property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538191/c-sharp-collection-indexed-by-property) and [How to write a class that (like array) can be indexed with `arr[key]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807310/how-to-write-a-class-that-like-array-can-be-indexed-with-arrkey)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a list of programs:

```
public static List<Program_TFT> Programs = new List<Program_TFT>();
```

Create a dictionary of programs where the key is the ProgramName:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Program_TFT> Programs = new Dictionary<string, Program_TFT>();
```

If you already have the list of programs somewhere, you can convert it directly into a dictionary by using `.ToDictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, Program_TFT> Programs = list.ToDictionary(x=>x.ProgramName);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, Program_TFT>` as the other answer suggested, or do this

```
Programs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProgramName == "Prog_1")
```

Line above assumes there will be a maximum of one program with the name, it will throw an error if more than one, or returns null if there isn't any.
You will need to manage duplications yourself.