# Not sure how to use this class

Tags: c#, class, xna

I want to have a class where I can `set` and `get` for each note. So I parse an XML file and with each `<note>` attribute in the file, I set and get the Note class. This was an alternative method to the `Dictionary<int,string>` that I had last time.

**So why did I change it?** Because for the double notes, (when the times were the same), the int within the dictionary would be a duplicate key and throw an error. So now, I've made a list with my `Note` class.

Here's the note class:

```
class Note
{
    public enum Notes
    {
        A, S, D, J, K, L,
    };

    public Notes CurrentNote { get; set; }

    public string Time { get; set; }

    public Note(Notes Note, string Time) {
        this.CurrentNote = Note;
        this.Time = Time;
    }
}
```

And then in my `NoteManager.cs`, I'll add to the list and set the values through that. But I'm not totally sure if this will work? I've never worked with getting and setting of classes. I tried adding the Notes to the list, but the way that I get the values doesn't seem to work. It gives a weird output.

> System.Linq.Enumberable+D_3a`1[Hit_Machine.Managers.Note]

Here's the NoteManager.cs Class:

```
class NoteManager : Game1
{
    public static List<Note> Notes = new List<Note>();

    public static void addNotes() {
        Notes.Add(new Note(Note.Notes.A, "22.22"));
        Notes.Add(new Note(Note.Notes.A, "33.33"));
        Notes.Add(new Note(Note.Notes.A, "55.55"));
    }

    public static void getNotes(Game1 Parent)
    {
        Game1.myGameText = Notes.Take(5).ToString();
    }
}
```

So what actually would be the proper way of using this method?

Comment: I'm guessing that the way that I'm using is wrong, and for each note that I set, it's just redefining the class, it's not actually saving that?

Comment: What text do you expect to appear? You basically create an enumerator that yields five elements of the `Notes` list. That's what the `ToString()` method returns ("I can enumerate some `Notes`").

Comment: Yeah, sorry, after some further research, I found that the method I was using was right. All I had to do was simply Notes[1].CurrentNote.ToString() simply returned what I needed. Thankyou for your interest :)

Comment: Use a collection type that allows duplicates.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries