# Best way to store List of <string,string> in csharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, c#-4.0, collections

I have to store list of two values similar to `<string,string>` and it is not like key,value.I can store it in objects or list,but whats the best way to store such data structures?
I have seen few persons referring to use  `List<Tuple<string, string>>` but what is the advantage of using above over other data structures like hashtable or object,

Comment: Well, `List<string, string>` doesn't exist. That's the main advantage

Comment: Does c# has List<string, string>() structure?

Comment: @AkashKC you're correct it absolutely doesnt

Comment: You can use `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

Comment: A `key` which is not unique is ... eh ... an unfortunate name, don't you think? And eventually it can lead to confusion.

Comment: like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297393/how-to-add-duplicate-keys-into-the-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a "key" to correspond to multiple values and efficiently find those values, then you can use `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.  This will be hashtable lookup by key into a list of values, so finding the values for a key will be O(1).

If you want to correlate the keys and values but don't need to look up by key then you can use `List<Tuple<string, string>>` or `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` if that suits you better, which you can iterate through and look up by index, but searching for a key will be O(N).

Answer (score 0):

Make a new class with two string properies and put it in the `List` instead of `Tuple<string, string>` or anything else weird construct. Main advantage is that everybody else knows whats inside the list and you dont have two magic strings. Cleanest and easiest way.