# I want to create a json file with same key and different value using dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, dictionary

Here is the sample i need to form. I tried hash set it is showing as key and value but i need my output to be in the below format.

```
[{
    "data": "Name"

},
{
    "data": "Description"
}]
```

My sample code:

```
var items = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (col.ColumnName !="DataType")
            {
                items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("data", 
col.ColumnName));
            }
        }
var lookup = items.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

When i try to add dictionary it throws me error saying key has already been added. Any guide to learn dictionary concepts in c#

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate keys in .NET dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries)

Comment: You should show us the code you already have.

Comment: A dictionary should have unique keys. You can't use a key more than once.

Comment: @Eliotjse, this post should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: I think it is not duplicate i tried all the possibilities so then asked the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given json is an array of objects and can be created with

```
var source = new List<object>{
    new Dictionary<string,object>{ { "data", "Name" }, },
    new Dictionary<string,object>{ { "data", "Description" }, },
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( source, Formatting.Indented );
```

[.NET fiddle Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wBDFh4)

Comment: Thanks exactly what i was looking for @Sir Rufo

Comment: You never accepted/upvoted any answer to your questions. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I upvoted but it did not reflect due to less points i have. But i marked it as useful thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add two key-value pairs to the same dictionary. The dictionary uses the key to calculate a hash. If you add two keys that are the same, you'll get a collision of the hashes. This will prevent the dictionary from working properly - when you try to get an item with that key, which item should the dictionary return?

Comment: I want to create duplicate and i achieved using previous answer.