# c# dictionary issue key value already exists.

Tags: c#, dictionary

hello stackoverflow u been trying to read a text file formatted all in one like separated with // example of line

```
ammoName\Arx\maxAmmo\14\startAmmo\14\clipName\galil_upgraded_zm\clipSize\35\shotCount\1\dropAmmoMin\1\dropAmmoMax\30\dropClipAmmoMin\0\
```

and i want to load it into a dictionary as key/value so like

key maxAmmo  value 14

but only issue i have here is these weapon files have some key values that are the same so i cant use dictionary i will post what i have tryied so far

```
Dictionary<string, string> WeaponStuff = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {

            string _line;
            while ((_line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                string[] keyvalue = _line.Split('\\');
                for (int i = 0; i < keyvalue.Length; i++)
                {
                    WeaponStuff.Add(keyvalue[i], keyvalue[i + 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var key in WeaponStuff.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key);//here are all the keys
        }
        textEdit1.Text = WeaponStuff["maxAmmo"];
```

basically all i want to do is read the file into a list<> or dictionary search up a key and display value in text box

then have a save button and when i hit save it will add all the new values and that form text boxes to the file but not sure how to get it to work as i cant seem to fix this issue

Comment: Make dictionary : Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` so you can store many things with the same key. Make sure when you add the first item to the dictionary you add a new list and then add items to the list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries

Comment: Yeah only issue i have with this is i have to load in a text file and split at certain point and then get key/values form one line and i never used this method before